# An Error: ElementNotInteractableException in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem with finding a WebElement in Selenium. I tried to fill the input field, this is the html:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="tp-fl" id="btnSearchStockAutoComplete">
                <span class="tp-icon tp-search tp-co-3 "></span>
            </div>
            <angucomplete placeholder="search" searchfields="Not Found" pause="400" set-focus="tpFocus" selectedobject="tpSelected" titlefield="label" inputclass="form-control form-control-small" matchclass="highlight" api="tpApi" disable="disableSearchBox" stockdetails="stockdetails" class="ng-isolate-scope">
                <div class="tp-re angucomplete-holder tp-width">
                    <div id="fulltextContainer" style="display: none" class="symbol-info tp-etc">
                    </div>
                    <input id="txt_search" class="search-box tp-co-1 tp-pa-rl-5 tp-re tp-bo-bo" type="text" placeholder="Search" onmouseup="this.select();" autocomplete="off">
                    <div id="auto-list-container" class="auto-list-container tp-bg-2 tp-co-1 tp-bo-4 tp-bo tp-width angucomplete-dropdown" style="min-width: 250px; display: none">
                        <div style="display: none" id="loading" class="tp-h-35 tp-pa-rl-10 angucomplete-searching">Searching ...</div>
                        <div style="display: none" id="norecord" class="tp-35 tp-pa-rl-10 angucomplete-searching">Not Found </div>
                        <div id="list_dropdown">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </angucomplete>
        </div>
```

this is my code in python:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    browser=webdriver.Chrome('path')
    inputTxt=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txt_search"]')
    inputTxt.send_keys('stock')
```

but when I run this program, it gives me an error and throws an exception, "selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable", I was wondering if there is any possible solution to this problem.

Comment: Do you need to interact with the page to trigger the search text field?  The error is suggesting the element exists but is not "interactable".

Comment: I want to fill the input element as I mentioned, I used send_keys() method, but it throws this exception. On the webpage itself, input element is interactable and I can write any text in it.

Comment: Is there more then one element with that id? There might be more than one where the first is not the one you want.

Comment: try `inputTxt.location_once_scrolled_into_view` which will scrolled the element into view. Then try send_keys.

Comment: @JeffC thanks for your help, I checked the page source and I found three other elements with exact same id, but in different divs with different ids and classes. Now I should try to focus on one of them, but the problem is how I am able to define the true css-selector for it. I used ```inputTxt=browser.find_element_by_css_selector('app-content#txt_search')``` (the input field I want with id='txt_search' is inside the app-content tag), but it throws NoSuchElementException, I'm confused what the right style is to reach this element?

Comment: When you write the CSS selector `app-content#txt_search`, that means the HTML is something like `<app-content id='txt_search'>...</app-content>`. Joined together with no space between means they are all part of the same element. What you want is either `app-content > #txt_search` (`>` indicates child) or `app-content #txt_search` (<space> indicates descendant). From the HTML posted in your question, I'm assuming you want space because I don't see the parent `<app-content>` tag.

Comment: This CSS reference will help: https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#overview. Also [Selenium Tips: CSS Selectors](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors) and [Taming Advanced CSS Selectors](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/taming-advanced-css-selectors/).

Comment: Try with this xpath `//div[@id="btnSearchStockAutoComplete"]/parent::div[@class="container"]//input[@id="txt_search"]`.. because it's hard to find easily this element uniquely using `cssSelector` if ther is multiple element with same `id`.

Comment: @JeffC Many thanks for your help, I used the space between the elements and It worked perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Great. I posted my comment as an answer since it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write the CSS selector `app-content#txt_search`, that means the HTML is something like `<app-content id='txt_search'>...</app-content>`. Joined together with no space between means they are all part of the same element. What you want is either `app-content > #txt_search` (`>` indicates child) or `app-content #txt_search` ( indicates descendant). From the HTML posted in your question, I'm assuming you want space because I don't see the parent `<app-content>` tag.